# I have an MMC snapin and several extension snapins. What defines the order that the extension snapins are displayed in? How to control this order?

Tags: mmc3

When loading the primary snapin the extension snapin nodes appear in some defined order, but I cannot see what defines the order.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the extension GUID defines the order. Snapins are listed Alphabetically based upon the GUID.

See:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MMC\NodeTypes{Your primary snapin GUID}\Extensions\NameSpace

This will list all of the guids that extend your snapin.